# Show the return stack

Tags: forth, gforth

Can you show the return stack in Forth?

`.S` shows the parameter stack. Is there a similar word showing the contents of the return stack?

I found SHOWSTACK on the web, but it does't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use this code if you are curious about the return stack:

```
: RTEST RP@ DUP >R RP@ RDROP SWAP - ;

RTEST CONSTANT RSTEP
RP@ CONSTANT RBIAS

: .RETURNSTACK \ --
  RP@ RBIAS 
  DO I @ U. RSTEP
  +LOOP CR ;
```

Comment: It's tempting to call this word `.R` in analogy with `.S`, but it may not be a good idea because there already is a word with that name.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such word in ANS Forth.

As for Gforth, there is the word `bt` since late 2012.